# How can I actively practice Python on my public transport commute?

Tags: python

What hardware (and software?) would allow me to **actively use Python whilst commuting on public transport?**

It's important that I practice actively; I don't learn well when learning is passive (e.g., podcasts or reading)

The suggestion should:

- be small enough that I can use with one hand (for when standing)
- allow [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) to be installed (i.e., `scikit-learn`, `pandas`, `numpy`, `matplotlib`, etc.)
- allow the storage of CSVs which can be read by `pandas`
- allow the storage of [offline Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/download.html) (to use when underground)
- not be too costly

Currently, I have an **Android phone** and an **Amazon Fire tablet**.

---

**Context:** I have a kid, and I am no longer finding the time to develop my technical skills out-of-office. I am not being given a broad enough range of projects to hone new skills, and I cannot practice unrelated skills on-the-job since it would visibly affect my productivity. The only deadtime I see remaining is my commute (on public transport).

Comment: This might be too basic for, you but as a beginner I really like the SoloLearn smartphone app.

Comment: I remember when that happened to me. Scary, isn't it? Keep at it, is all I can say. Ever new skill you learn increases your value.

Answer (score 1):

Try these from the Amazon app store:

[QPython](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AP36S4Y) Free

[QPython3 Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F2FZMO2) $2.99

Or this if you want Python 2.6:

[Python IDE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M342RUM)

I haven't seen Anaconda available for any android.  It might be, I just haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Install termux either from the play store or from f-droid and get access to a full linux environment including python.